# PHP App Engine Development Environment doesn't honor verify_peer

Tags: php, google-app-engine, file-get-contents, google-app-engine-php

SDK release: "1.9.37", timestamp: 1460570478
OSX 10.11.4 Python 2.7.10

When using file_get_contents() in the dev environment to connect to a server with a self signed certificate - we have started to get the error below.

We have not had to work under these conditions for a while, so not sure when this error was introduced.

```
file_get_contents(https://10.10.10.10:10000/script): failed to open stream: SSL certificate error - certificate invalid or non-existent, [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

Exmaple code:

```
<?php

//$url = 'https://mockbin.org/bin/5b867989-b414-4d75-97db-10f346893574';
$url = 'https://a.public.server:10000';

$context = [ 'http' => [ 'method' => 'GET' ], 'ssl' => [ 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed'=> true ] ];
$context = stream_context_create($context);
$resp = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

echo $resp;
```

The code works when deployed, it's just trying to develop and test locally that we get the issue.

We are setting both *verify_peer* and *verify_peer_name* as **false** - as above, this works in App Engine proper, but not the development environment.

With mockbin we get an unrelated error - it's simply there for testing.

Comment: For those experiencing the same problem - Google have confirmed that this is a bug with at least the current SDK. There are no details as to a work around, or ETA for a fix.